# Understanding the range issue in binary seach problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

EDIT:
Add more details about the logic behind the code.
Thx to @Stef.

I am trying to do an algorithm problem in LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-duplicate-number/).

Below is my method to solve this, which uses binary search thinking.
The basic logic of the code is, I am trying to find the duplicated number in the range [1, n] inclusive using binary search.

For instance, if I am going to find the duplicated num in the list [1, 3, 4, 2, 2].
Firstly, count the midpoint of [1, 4], because the start point is 1, the endpoint is 4, hence the midpoint is 2. Then I use the cntRange function to count how many numbers in the list are among the range of [1, 2]. if the number of numbers(we have 1, 2, 2, three numbers) is more than it should be (should be 2), we shrink the range by setting the endpoint as midpoint and continue the binary search, until we finish the search and we return the present value of start point, which is the duplicated one.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findRepeatNumber(vector<int> &nums) {
        // special case we return -1
        if (nums.size() < 2) {
            return -1;
        }

        // binary search to cnt the numbers in certain range
        int start = 1;
        int end = nums.size() - 1;
        while (end >= start) {

            int mid = ((end - start) >> 1) + start;
            int cnt = cntRange(nums, start, mid);

            if (end == start) {
                if (cnt > 1) {
                    return start;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (cnt > (mid - start + 1))
                end = mid;
            else
                start = mid + 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int cntRange(vector<int> &nums, int start, int end) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            if (nums[i] >= start && nums[i] <= end)
                cnt++;
        }
        return cnt;
    }
};
```

This method passes in LeetCode, however, I am curious about the range [1, n], what if the range is [0, n-1]?

I tried with two test sets:
one is [0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6]
the other is [2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 5, 3]
they all failed, so I go back to my code to try to fix this.

I initialize the start int to 0 instead and change the cnt compare condition
from cnt > (mid - start + 1) to cnt > (mid - start).
But in this case, only the first test is passed, I still can not pass the second one.

I still think this problem arose in the cnt compare process, but do not know how to solve this.
Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. You will probably attract more answers if you explained the algorithm and logic behind your code. Right now, we don't know what you want to do; we only know that you wrote some code that doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: `start` should start at zero, I think. Also, in `cntRange` you seem to be using `start` as a value (comparing to `nums[i]`) where it's really an index into `nums`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, the start and the end are just the range of numbers, which are not the indexs. The reason I set the start to 1 is that that in the original problem, the numbers are among the range of [1, n], hence the start should be 1. You can see that I tried to change the start to 0 to solve the problem which has a range of [0, n-1] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem for the 2 cases you've mentioned is with:

```
start = mid + 1;
```

The value of mid can never go negative and therefore the minimum value for start can never be less than 1 after the first time this line is reached. This means you never see the value at index 0 when doing binary search.